# Is it possible to curl an npm package into nexus 2?

Tags: curl, npm, nexus

I've tried using the follow command:

`curl -v file=@random-number-generator-1.0.0.tgz -u admin:admin123 -X POST "http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/npm-hosted-01/random-number-generator-1.0.0.tgz"`

Is it possible to curl an npm package into a Nexus 2 repo?

Answer (score 1):

Not for Repo 2, you'd have to replicate what npm is doing, and it is a bit more involved than a simple PUT.  Why not just use "npm publish"?

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/publish

BTW, in Repo 3 you can use the REST API.

https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM3/Components+API#ComponentsAPI-NPM